# Filter a list from another list kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin

I have the following 2 lists

```
val list1= listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6)
val list2= listOf(3,4,5,7,8)
```

I want to remove all the elements present in list2 from list1.

I tried with

```
    val l3=list1.filter {e1-> list2.any {e2-> e2==e1 } }
    println(l3)
```

I am getting the output as `[3, 4, 5]` instead of `[1, 2, 6]`

Comment: Did you forget to invert the condition in the `filter`? `!list2.any {e2-> e2==e1 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the previous answer would give you the desired result, I would encourage  you to use Kotlin's inbuilt feature to use overloaded minus operator for this operation

```
data class Test(val t:String)

fun main() {
    val list1= listOf(Test("a"),Test("b"),Test("c"),Test("d"),Test("e"),Test("f"))
    val list2= listOf(Test("a"),Test("b"),Test("c"))
    val result = list1 - list2
    println(result)

}
```

*The output will be*

`[Test(t=d), Test(t=e), Test(t=f)]`

The reason why I used a custom class is that one can argue that, It can work with a list of plain numbers but not with custom classes, Well Kotlin does an equality check, You must make sure you override the `equals()` method and this will work as expected. Since data class does that out of the box I did not need to do it.

Answer (score 3):

[subtract](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/subtract.html) is doing exactly that.

`.subtract()` returns a `Set`, so if a `List` is needed `.toList()` needs to be added after *list1.subtract(list2)*:

```
val list1 = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val list2 = listOf(3, 4, 5, 7, 8)

val result = list1.subtract(list2)

println(result)   // Output: [1, 2, 6]
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be as long-winded as `….subtract(…)`, even — the related [`minus()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/minus.html) function is an operator, so you can simply do `list1 - list2`. (I love single-character answers!)

Comment: Subtract has also an infix version: _list1 subtract list2_.

Comment: Is the only difference between `minus` and `subtract` that the first returns a `List` and the latter a `Set`?

Answer (score 1):

simply negate the `any` with a `!`, like

```
val l3=list1.filter {e1-> !list2.any {e2-> e2==e1 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard JDK method `Collection::removeAll(Collection<T>)`, however it requires `list3` to be mutable:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val list1 = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    val list2 = listOf(3,4,5,7,8)

    val list3 = list1.toMutableList()
    list3.removeAll(list2)
    println(list3)
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 6]
```